# CSS div slide on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is a webkit rendering bug or what however;
I have a Masonary style grid with many different images. I have it set so that when you hover over them on a desktop browser a div with text slides up (text is permanently visible on mobile devices). All works lovely except in Chrome and Safari the text slide up only works on the first column, when you hover over the images in any other column the text never slides up and I don't know why (it works fine in IE and FF)

```css
    .gallery{
     -webkit-column-count:5;
     -moz-column-count:5;
     column-count:5;
     -moz-column-gap:1em;
     column-gap:1em;
     margin-top:7%;
     padding-bottom:5%;
     }
    
    .item{
     display:inline-block;
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     }
    
    .description {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:-100px;
     left: 0;
     width:100%;
     font-family:Archivo Narrow;
     z-index: 1000;
     -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease;
     transition:all 0.6s ease;
     }
    
    .description_text {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
     padding:10px;
     top:0;
     z-index:4;
     -webkit-transition:opacity.2s;
     -moz-transition:opacity.2s;
     -o-transition:opacity.2s;
     transition:opacity.2s;
     color: #fff;
     }
    
    img:hover + .description{
     bottom:0;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="gallery">
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building1.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 1</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building2.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 2</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building3.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 3</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="building4.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 4</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building5.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 5</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building6.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 6</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building7.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 7</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building8.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 8</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="building9.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 9</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

In this instance the first column displays images 1-6 the rest are in the second column which is where the transition stops working. Any ideas?

[image]
In the image I have tried to highlight the text div which slides up (this if from  Cedric's jsfiddle, as you can see in Chrome the div is just viewable on the first two images but it is not there on the rest and the hover effect does not work

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome? Spent some time playing around without any luck, but there are logged webkit bugs against column module and positioned elements.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking but I have just tested in Safari which replicates the same issues as Chrome and seeing as they use -webkit- engine it must be that - Thanks for trying as well, just glad I'm not the only one with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have managed to fix this. All I did was add
-webkit-column-count:1; to the .description{} set of commands in my css and it now works

```
.description {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-100px;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        font-family:Archivo Narrow;
        z-index: 1000;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease;
        transition:all 0.6s ease;
-webkit-column-count:1;
        }
```

But this only works for Chrome and not Safari

Comment: As in Chrome 54, `-webkit-column-count:1;` was needed to make my transitions work properly on the first column (of two, on the second column worked without a fix). Safari 10 wasn't needed, same for FF 51.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but behaviour seems to be the same in Firefox and Chrome from here.

However, your text overlays jump around, since they are set to be visible in case of `img:hover`, which is not not the case as soon as `.description` appears and is naturally hovered then.

As a workaround, you may want to apply the rule making your text visible to `.description:hover` too.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbb5Ljwy/1/) demonstrating that.

Comment: Hi @Cedric I was worried you would say it's working fine on your PC. However it might be my PC as I have just checked your JSFiddle on Chrome on my PC and again the text description is not sliding up on any of the images that are not in column 1, The first two slide up fine but the rest do not. If I could attach images I would

Comment: I have just added an image to try to further explain the issue

Comment: @cedric Your fiddle doesn't work on Chrome for me either.

Comment: Ok, I had been testing on Linux. On Windows, however, there seems to be an issue with `column-count`.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to the webkit team hopefully they will either resolve or tell me how to do it so it works across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the column-count attribute, but I think it solves:

```css
.gallery{
     /*-webkit-column-count:5;
     -moz-column-count:5;
     column-count:5;
     -moz-column-gap:1em;
     column-gap:1em;*/
     margin-top:7%;
     padding-bottom:5%;
  
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .item{
     display:inline-block;
     /*width:100%;*/
     height:auto;
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
    }
    
    .description {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:-100px;
     left: 0;
     width:100%;
     font-family:Archivo Narrow;
     z-index: 1000;
     -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease;
     transition:all 0.6s ease;
     }
    
    .description_text {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
     padding:10px;
     top:0;
     z-index:4;
     -webkit-transition:opacity.2s;
     -moz-transition:opacity.2s;
     -o-transition:opacity.2s;
     transition:opacity.2s;
     color: #fff;
     }
    
    .item:hover .description{
     bottom:0;
     }
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 1</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 2</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 3</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 4</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 5</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 6</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 7</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 8</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://sp5.fotolog.com/photo/21/61/103/roqro_85/1229095304477_f.jpg" />
       <div class="description">
        <div class="description_text">
         <p>Building 9</p>
         <p>London EC2</p>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @alexqoliveira I have removed the column count, but because this is the Masonry grid layout (not all images same height - bit like pinterest layout) I need the column count to be included, thats why I'm thinking it might be Chrome itself

Comment: I do not know why, but chrome treated differently when has elements with attribute 'position:absolute'. . . .